# Getting "There were deployment errors, Continue?" error in visual studio 2015 xamarin android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android

I am very new in xamarin development. Recently I install xamarin with visual studio 2015 in windows 10. I have created a simple project in xamarin android. It build perfectly but when I try to run the project in emulator getting "There were deployment errors, continue?" popup message.

[image: Please check the image].

I have googled and do not get any proper solution. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: You have to look up the error in the output window (bottom left 2nd tab on your picture)

Comment: I recently faced this issue but after specific package installation. However, I resolved this issue by defining the package name(lowercase) in project properties. In fact I didn't get any failed log in output window.

Answer (score 5):

had the same problem on windows 64 bit
i'm using the latest android sdk build tools at this moment (v25.0.1)
just installed jdk 9 and a 32 bit version of jdk(version 7) due to this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/)

then changed the jdk path in tools>options>Xamarin>Android settings.
restart visual studio. clean and rebuild. that's it.

Comment: This sould be the best answer !

Comment: 1. Restarting visual studio
2. Cleaning
3. Rebuilding
4. Deploying to device

Comment: Microsoft's JDK [ Microsoft-25199 (build 11.0.12+7) ] had a bug. After changing to any other JDK, the problem is gone!

Answer (score 5):

You may have wrongly selected "target Android version" to version your emulator is running on.

Make sure that these two are aligning.

**VS -> (right click on project) -> properties - > Android Manifest (tab) -> Target Android version (drop down)**

Answer (score 2):

In my system, I'm using latest Android SDK build tools at this moment(v26.0.1) and Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.7.4.

In Regedit the Android SDK also same Visual Studio tools>options>Xamarin>Android settings. But the problem was same with me.

In my case, I changed the Package Name in Android Manifest then the problem has been solved.

[image]

Comment: Tried this, good idea anyway, but sadly wasn't a fix for very long.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, which I solved by editing the Android emulator on Android Device Manager giving it a processor of both 32 and 64 bits (x86_64).

After doing this, Android Device Manger downloaded and updated the Emulator configuration. After this I was able to run and debug my app with no problems on Android Emulator.

Answer (score -1):

you should increase free space in drive C and empty temp folder

Answer (score -2):

To help you troubleshoot the deployment error, I'll need more information about the specific error message you're encountering and the context of your MAUI application.

You should follow the link :https://youtu.be/AWKzBmgev6Q

OR follow the following steps to resolve the issue

Here are some general steps you can follow to diagnose and resolve deployment errors in a MAUI application:

Check Error Messages: The first step is to carefully read and understand the error message. Error messages often provide valuable information about what went wrong.

Check the Output Window: Look at the output window in your development environment (e.g., Visual Studio) for more detailed error messages and stack traces. This can help pinpoint the issue.

Review Dependencies: Ensure that you have all the required dependencies and NuGet packages installed correctly. Sometimes, missing or outdated dependencies can lead to deployment errors.

Check Configuration: Verify your project's configuration settings. Make sure you have selected the correct target platform and build configuration (e.g., Debug or Release).

Clean and Rebuild: Try cleaning and rebuilding your solution. Sometimes, a corrupted build or cached files can cause deployment issues.

Update MAUI: Ensure that you are using the latest version of MAUI. Updates often include bug fixes and improvements that could resolve your issue.

Platform-Specific Issues: If your MAUI app targets multiple platforms (e.g., Android, iOS, Windows), the error may be platform-specific. Check platform-specific documentation and logs for additional details.

Check Permissions: If your app requires specific permissions, make sure they are properly configured in the app manifest or settings.