# On Xamarin in Visual Studio 2022 I keep getting "There were deployment errors continue?" I'm on windows 11 and I'm using an android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-emulator

The model emulator I'm using is a pixel 5 or android 11.0, I've tried downloading the intelx86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and resetting visual studio, but nothing has worked, I even tried to create a new project but that didn't work either.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPUhX.png)

Comment: you need to look at the deployment log to see what the actual errors are.  There should be an option in the View menu to show different debug windows, including the deployment log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The thing is even when I don't write any code it still won't run in Xamarin.

Comment: You can try to remove the bin and obj foders and try again.

Comment: seems this problem has a long history since 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694554/getting-there-were-deployment-errors-continue-error-in-visual-studio-2015-xa/52041677

Comment: I've been seeing this a lot as well. There is nothing at all in the output. Restarting the Android emulator doesn't help. Restarting Visual Studio 2022 is the only way to fix it I've found. I'm on Windows 10 using an API30 emulator though.

Answer (score 3):

Restart ADB Server via Tools -> Android -> Restart ADB Server then it works. You need to restart ADB Server every time restart the debugger.

It is a bug in VS2022.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the path to your project is too long or on that path you have accented chars like ã, ç or º or ª and maybe others.
Try creating your project in your Visual Studio 2022 standard/default directory like C:\Users\YourName\source\repos Best Regards!